# 301 redirect of main URL

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite

I have changed my website's domain. For eg. www.abc.com to www.xyz.com.
Now I want to set 301 redirect for www.abc.com to www.xyz.com.
I have checked **Catalog > URL Rewrite Management**.
Is that right way to do it? Or how can I do that redirect for the main URL from Magento backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this through your .htaccess file. Unfortunately, Magento does not have a built in functionality for redirecting root domains.

Add this to your .htaccess file. It will 301 redirect all requests from the old domain to the new one.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.old.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: How can i redirect my abc.com to www.abc.com by using 301 redirect

Answer (score -1):

Best way will be you can do it is if you can access database.

```
UPDATE core_config_data SET value = "www.xyz.com/" WHERE value = "www.abc.com/"
```

Then delete your cache and session folder inside **magento_root_folder/var**

### OR

If you can access your backend from your old URL then change **Base URL** in:

```
System > Configuration > General > Web > Unsecure
System > Configuration > General > Web > Secure
```

And clear your cache and session after it.